# Why does the compiler require `delete [] p` versus `delete p[]`?

Tags: c++, language-design, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

In C++, if you want to dynamically allocate an array, you can do something like this:

```
int *p;
p = new int[i];  // i is some number
```

However, to delete the array, you do...

```
delete[] p;
```

Why isn't it `delete p[]`?  Wouldn't that be more symmetrical with how it was originally created?  What is the reason (if there is any) why the language was designed this way?

Comment: Why the downvote/vote to close?  What can I do to improve the question?

Comment: @Deflect: That was mine, Usually 'why was this language construct chosen?' questions are simply not constructive because there is no objective, reasonable answer. However, in this case there are a few decent reasons, so I may have judged too soon (I removed my downvote quite quickly).

Comment: @KillianDS: Okay, that makes sense.  Thanks for replying!  [and reassuring me that I'm not totally off-base :)]

Comment: @KillianDS: Well, then why not just answer by "there's no serious reason, other languages do this and this and it just happened that C++ goes its way"?

Comment: I don't know how useful this is, but this is the way I'd read the code in English: p is an integer pointer; p is a new integer array of length i; delete the array p.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One reason could be to make these cases more distinct.

```
int ** p;
delete[] p
delete p[1];
```

If it were `delete p[]` then a one character error would have pretty nasty consquences.

Comment: This is especially true, in that in early C++, you had to specify the number of elements in the `[]`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sounds like that's the answer to me. `delete p[4]` would be ambiguous.

Comment: `delete []p[1];` is also valid, and compiler must know the programmer's intent!

Answer (score 2):

Because array decays to pointer when passing as parameter to function (or operator). So delete p[] would be simply equivalent to delete p.

**[edit]**
We may think of delete as of special template operator. The operator should be able to distingish between p and p[] to pick the right "specialization" (non-array or array deletion). However, template argument deduction rules make this choice impossible (due to array decaying we can't distingish between p[] and p when deducing the argument).

So we can't use operator with name *delete* for both casees and need to introduce another operator delete[] with diffrent name (suffix [] can be treated as part of operator's name) for array case.

**[edit 2]**  Note. delete p[] is not valid sintax at all according to the current standard. The reasoning above only shows problems that could araise if we would try to interpret delete p[] using existing c++ concepts.

Comment: No, it is not equivalent. Using one in place of another is undefined behavior.

Comment: @sharptooth: ? passing an array into templated function instead of pointer is UB? I think about delete as about templated operator and this operator can't pick the right specialization because it can't distingish between p[] and p when deducing the argument. So we need to introduce a special operator delete[] for arrays instead of using the same operator name

Comment: @sharptooth: of course, but it's unrelated to my answer. I said only that delete p and delete p[] are equivalent statements (perhaps, both expose UB if p is an _array_ created by new int[i])